# jQuery : Replacing Fading with Sliding

Tags: jquery, effect

I have the below script to hide the content of one div and show another

```
$("#"+objCurrentDiv).fadeOut("slow",function(){
  $("#"+objNewDiv).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

This is giving me the fading effect.Now i want to repalce the fade effect with sliding (left to right.
I tried the slide in show method, but could not succeed. Can any one help me to rewrite it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the standard function .slideDown and .slideUp will do the effect vertically, you have to use .animate like this:

```
$("#"+objCurrentDiv).animate({'width':'0%','display':'none'},"slow",function(){
  $("#"+objNewDiv).animate({'width':'100%','display':'block'},"slow");
});
```